# How do I randomly display images from Parse.com

Tags: ios, objective-c, random, uitableview, parse-platform

I'd like to randomly display profile pictures in a `UITableViewCell`.

My table is set up as a way to filter. I have one table setup on Parse for users which also contains a category column and picture column. I want to query by the category (each cell row is a category as exampled below), and randomly display image(s) in the `UITableViewCell`.

So the table would be set up such as:

Category A

Category B

Category C

Each cell will have `UIImageViews` in them, and I'd like to randomly display images in each cell.

Here's what I have tried, but no luck.

```
// in ViewDidLoad
self.theArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"A", @"B", @"C", @"D", nil];

// in cellForRowAtIndexPath
cell.label.text = [self.theArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

PFQuery * query = [PFUser query]; 
[query whereKey:@"category" equalTo:cell.label.text]; 
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:(NSArray *objects, NSError error) {

    if (error)
    {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    }
    else
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < objects.count; i++)
        {
            self.profilePicObject = [objects objectAtIndex:i];

            int imgRandom = random() % [objects count];

            self.randomProfilePicObject = [objects objectAtIndex:imgRandom];

            self.imageFile = [self.randomProfilePicObject objectForKey:@"imageFile"];
            NSURL * imageFileURL = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:self.imageFile.url];
            NSData * imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageFileURL];
            UIImage * aImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imageData];

            cell.profilePicOne.image = aImage;
        }
    }
}];
```

EDIT:

I have modified the code above, and it is working now. What would be the most efficient way to modify this to fill in more than one `UIImageView` in a cell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < objects.count; i++)
    {
        //self.profilePicObject = [objects objectAtIndex:i];

        int randomImgNumber = arc4random_uniform(5); // You could several many times the same picture !!!
        self.profilePicObject = [objects objectAtIndex:randomImgNumber];

        self.imageFile = [self.profilePicObject objectForKey:@"imageFile"];
        NSURL * imageFileURL = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:self.imageFile.url];
        NSData * imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageFileURL];
        UIImage * aImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imageData];

       // aImage = [objects objectAtIndex:randomImgNumber];

        cell.profilePicOne.image = aImage;
    }
```

Comment: Looks like my query isn't returning any objects. I have the labels in my table set up in an array.

Comment: I not sure to understand... you have an array for the label, and use query for the pictures ???

Comment: No. The array matches the categories in my Parse table. I want to query and match the category, and then display pictures of users that are under that category

Comment: ^ missing in block: `[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock: ^ (NSArray *objects`

Comment: Any advice to modify this to display more than one image?